# function factorear (num)

Tags: javascript, array

// Factorear el número recibido como parámetro y devolver en un array
// los factores por los cuales se va dividiendo a dicho número (De menor a mayor)
// Ej: factorear(180) --> [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5] Ya que 1x2x2x3x3x5 = 180 y son todos números primos
// Tu código:

```
function factorear(num) {
var resultado = [];
for (var i = 2; i < num; i++) {
if (num % i === 0) {
  resultado.push(num % i === 0);
}
}
return resultado;
}
```

Cual es el error en este código que no me deja retornar correctamente?

Comment: Cual es el error en este código que no me deja retornar correctamente?

Comment: Es un procedimiento matemático más que un error de código. pero tu error es solo considerar que un divisor tiene repetibilidad de 1. osea el 2 no podría salir dos veces.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque aquí no se exponen ningún problema y el autor solo deja el enunciado de su problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tratando de ajustar a tu código de prueba:

```js
function factorear(num) {
var resultado = [];
for (var i = 2; i < num+1; i++) {
console.log("probar factor: ",i);
if (num % i === 0) {
  console.log("agregar factor: ",i);
  
  resultado.push(i);
  num/=i;
  i-=1;
}
}
return resultado;
}

let result=factorear(180)
console.log("Factores: ",result);
```

Errores encontrados:

- Solo considera un factor con repetibilidad de 1, si saliera 2 veces no funcionaría. Por ello he modificado el `i` dentro del *loop* para que intente de nuevo el mismo `i`.

Comment: Gracias @AlfredoMaussa por la ayuda en este hermoso camino de la programación !!! Saludos